# Poweredge 2850 linux USB boot

Tags: linux, dell, dell-poweredge

I've made a bootable usb for Centos 6.5 OS by downloading the minimal.iso and dd'ing it unto my usb.

I've configured the Bios to boot from said usb, and it seems to do that. However: I've been getting the following error every version of linux I put unto the usb:

> Isolinux.bin missing or corrupted

Does anybody have a clue how I can fix this? Hours of google have not helped me one bit.

Any documentation on basic linux webserver set up on a dell poweredge 2850 is also greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

So I've got the installer running. I've found a post [here](http://www.fixya.com/support/t1848433-not_boot_dell_poweredge_from_usb_cd) in which they say:

> try reseting your bios. This should return it to default: hit f2 as the server boots to get to the boot set up. Once in, hit alt+e then alt+f it should beep everytime.

I then set USB CONTROLLER - On with BIOS support
and made sure I set USB Flash Drive Emulation to Hard Disk.

Then rebooted, went into the boot set up again with f2 and changed the Hard-Disk Drive Sequence. Putting my Hard-disk-emulated USB Flash Drive as 1.

Now here comes the next question..

Now that I'm in the installer, it's asking me:

> What type of media contains the installation image?

This is ofcourse a Hard drive as we set our USB to be Hard-disk-emulated. So I select Hard drive. Now however, it's asking me what partition I want to use.

How do I know what partition my Hard-disk-emulated USB Drive is?

Comment: Does it work on any other computer?

Comment: The usb boots fine from my linux based desktop.

Comment: UEFI boot. Try disabling/playing with this form BIOS.

Comment: Do you perhaps know if the formatting of my USB makes any difference? Right now it's FAT32.

Comment: @KonradGajewski a 2850 doesn't have UEFI